# How to add C Editor in RCP application

Tags: c, eclipse, editor, rcp

I need help with adding C editor in RCP application. I add needed jars: org.eclipse.cdt.ui and org.eclipse.cdt.ui, in my build path. After this I can recognize class CEditor in plugin.xml -> Extension -> Extension Element Details -> class. I run my application, and when I try to open C file I get this message:

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "com.ivan.visualizer" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditor".

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `Require-Bundle` in your plugin's MANIFEST.MF file to list all the plugins that your plugin uses. Trying to put plugin jars on  the build path won't work.

You can set the Require-Bundle in the MANIFEST.MF editor on the 'Dependencies' tab in the 'Required Plugins' section.